# Setting up React Styleguidist with Next.js and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-styleguidist

I am trying to setup React styleguidist with next.js and typescript, but I keep walking into problems. My current styleguide.config.js looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  components: './components/**/*.tsx',
  propsParser: require('react-docgen-typescript').withCustomConfig('./tsconfig.json', {
    propFilter: { skipPropsWithoutDoc: true },
  }).parse,
  webpackConfig: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        static: path.join(__dirname, 'static'),
        lib: path.join(__dirname, 'lib'),
      },
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'ts-loader',
            },
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                outputPath: 'images',
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

If i just have a very basic component with just basic jsx everything works, but once I want to assign props for example for styled components, typescript starts complaining. Also importing stuff from outside the `components` folder is causing issues.
Can maybe someone point me to an example of how they set it up?

Comment: you can check the https://github.com/ohearonkg/next-exploration